# javascript - find line that starts with string and print select characters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to parse a multline string with javascript and in the example below return "Dan Smith". My filter is close but not quite there.

```js
var header = "Resent-From:<joesmith@domain.com>\nFrom:Dan Smith <dansmith@domain.com>\nTo:Bill Smith <dansmith@domain.com>\n"
console.log(header)

var filter = header.split("From:").pop();
console.log(filter)
```

edit:
The goal was to retrieve "Dan Smith"

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @Spectric Says it in the question *example below return "Dan Smith"*

Comment: What is unclear? OP says exactly what they want in the question. They gave sample input. They stated they wanted "Dan Smith" and they gave their attempt.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello. your answer was perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it your way, you would need another split

```js
var header = "Resent-From:<joesmith@domain.com>\nFrom:Dan Smith <dansmith@domain.com>\nTo:Bill Smith <dansmith@domain.com>\n"


var filter = header.split("From:").pop().split("<").shift().trim();
console.log(filter)
```

Basic regular expression can match the name.

```js
var header = "Resent-From:<joesmith@domain.com>\nFrom:Dan Smith <dansmith@domain.com>\nTo:Bill Smith <dansmith@domain.com>\n"
console.log(header.match(/\nFrom:([^<]+)</)[1].trim());
```